# Not able to get the url and the text of a clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a small firefox extension, which requires to detect each url clicked, then it saves the url and the corresponding text. In other words, I want store all the url and corresponding text which  causes page change or some kind of network activity.

The jquery code I am using

```
$('*').click(function(){
    var url = this.href;
    if(url!=undefined){
        console.log(url+ "   " + this.text);
    }
});
```

This code works fine in most of the cases, but when I try to get the links on websites like Evernote, Box.com, Dropbox it simply doesn't work. I am not able to fathom out the reason. For example on box.com, if I click on any file, above code is not able to return me the url and text and very similar situation in Dropbox as well.

Are there some limitation of the code I am using? Any help/idea is appreciated.

**Edit:**

For a box file, on inspecting element by Firebug, I get

```
<a data-validate="filename not_empty_item_type" data-behavior="edit_in_place" data-item_type="folder" data-item_id="1816357023" data-field="name" data-url="/index.php?rm=box_files_update_item_info" class="item_link item_name_text edit_in_place item_name dnd" href="/files/0/f/1816357023/public_test">public_test</a>
```

It does have a 'href'.

A box [link](https://app.box.com/s/m0pxf08s1tr916omx5r4) to test it.

Code works perfectly fine when I click on the updates (with a globe image) and files (with a folder image) link on top of the page in box.com

Comment: Give me a link to some Box.com example, and I can figure it out for you.

Comment: Do the elements, on those sites where it fails to work, have an `href`? Or is their click functionality triggered by JavaScript, based on another property?

Comment: Make sure that they have the hreg attribute, they might be using onclick or something similar

Comment: why are you using `*`? you are going to be firing a event for each parent in the hierarchy of the element you click on, use the anchor tag `$("a").click...`

Comment: @DavidThomas I can see a href for the element in box.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I used it because in case of evernote I observed there was no <a> tag, but instead a <span> inside a <div>. Not sure whether my approach is totally correct.

Comment: @Jor-el, i see, then make sure to use stopPropagation within the event function so that the parent elements do not trigger the event also

Answer (score 1):

How do you load your script? I mean, maybe its a obvious answer but your code uses Jquery. A lot of sites actually use that, so your code works. But for example dropbox does not use it, hence it will never work.

edit:

Putt your script in a doc. ready function. I tried this, and it worked for me to get the URL.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
```

If you encounter some problems, try to use it with noConflict mode as in;

```
 jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
```

---

update 2

How I found it:
I simply used my browsers console. While "executing" your script, it got an error back.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
```

This means the DOM is not ready yet. Or, havent actually tested it. It could be that Jquery is in conflict. Hence using Jquery rather than $

Comment: The above script is content-script of firefox extension and I am loading it for every page. I am also loading jquery lib for each page myself. So not dependent on whether website use jquery or not.

Comment: Can you be sure, to just simply fire a jquery event like, on page load with an alert? That would rule it out for sure.

Comment: I am sure that jquery is loaded, as above code works perfectly fine when I click on the updates (with a globe image) and files (with a folder image) link on top of the page in box.com. It doesn't work when a mouse click is performed on folders or files.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly fine for box.com. But the problem persist for website like dropbox.com, evernote.com. I have pasted a case of each over [here](http://pastebin.com/E9gY5tUV). In case of evernote though, there is no href, but dropbox do have. Also, can you also tell me how you figured out the problem.

Comment: for some funny reasons, the code runs fine when I run in my browser, but when I run it via firefox extension it doesnt work for dropbox.com.